# Firebase nodemailer after deploy

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

**Hello.**
My problem is, when I using nodemailer at localhost I am able to send email with nodemailer with the same exact credentials. But when I am at the point to deploy, firebase logs says me invalid login. Tho I checked the security/lesssecureapps option too.
I am wondering why not working properly on production, but doing its job at development phase.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
   host: hostname,
   port: 465,
   secure: true,
   requireTLS: true,
   auth: {
      user: email,
      pass: password
   },
   logger: true
})
type contactMe = {
   name: string,
   email: string,
   msg: string,
}
const sendMail = async (data: contactMe) => {
    const info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: email,
        to: email,
        subject: "Job offer - " + data.name,
        html: data.msg
    })
    console.log(`Message sent: ${info.response}`)
    return !!info.response
}
export const contactWithMe = functions.https.onCall(async (data: contactMe, ctx) => {
    console.log(data)
    const info = await sendMail(data)
return { succes: info }
```

})

**Firebase logs:**

```
contactWithMe
[2022-01-07 10:58:36] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP/6.7.2[client:6.7.2]
11:58:36.671 AM
contactWithMe
[2022-01-07 10:58:36] DEBUG [iImP28YjIl0] Resolved smtp.gmail.com as 142.250.152.108 [cache miss]
11:58:36.840 AM
contactWithMe
[2022-01-07 10:58:36] INFO [iImP28YjIl0] Secure connection established to 142.250.152.108:465
11:58:36.856 AM
contactWithMe
[2022-01-07 10:58:36] DEBUG [iImP28YjIl0] SMTP handshake finished
11:58:37.206 AM
contactWithMe
[2022-01-07 10:58:37] INFO [iImP28YjIl0] User "moleszkf@gmail.com" failed to authenticate
11:58:37.207 AM
contactWithMe
[2022-01-07 10:58:37] DEBUG [iImP28YjIl0] Closing connection to the server using "end"
11:58:37.208 AM
contactWithMe
[2022-01-07 10:58:37] ERROR Send Error: Invalid login: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv
11:58:37.208 AM
contactWithMe
[2022-01-07 10:58:37] ERROR 534-5.7.14 x6AR0OXK6C0lYv4o-AWh169fS51p8n-AthFA2eNnSx55fdZCwdsoH98i4oekJP0XB0q_5
11:58:37.208 AM
contactWithMe
[2022-01-07 10:58:37] ERROR 534-5.7.14 6T99FVuv8hMjZaixfJqiRpAKaPpmygCC_o0pVNe0s2TtQSzje2PdHzPF5ErFtmcM>
11:58:37.208 AM
contactWithMe
[2022-01-07 10:58:37] ERROR 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
11:58:37.208 AM
contactWithMe
[2022-01-07 10:58:37] ERROR 534-5.7.14 Learn more at
11:58:37.208 AM
contactWithMe
[2022-01-07 10:58:37] ERROR 534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 m14sm3076179iow.54 - gsmtp 
11:58:37.210 AM
contactWithMe
Unhandled error Error: Invalid login: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv 534-5.7.14 x6AR0OXK6C0lYv4o-AWh169fS51p8n-AthFA2eNnSx55fdZCwdsoH98i4oekJP0XB0q_5 534-5.7.14 6T99FVuv8hMjZaixfJqiRpAKaPpmygCC_o0pVNe0s2TtQSzje2PdHzPF5ErFtmcM> 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 m14sm3076179iow.54 - gsmtp at SMTPConnection._formatError (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19) at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1536:34) at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:540:26) at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:947:20) at SMTPConnection._onData (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:749:14) at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (/workspace/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:189:44) at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28) at TLSSocket.emit (domain.js:537:15) at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12) at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9) { code: 'EAUTH', response: '534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv\n' + '534-5.7.14 x6AR0OXK6C0lYv4o-AWh169fS51p8n-AthFA2eNnSx55fdZCwdsoH98i4oekJP0XB0q_5\n' + '534-5.7.14 6T99FVuv8hMjZaixfJqiRpAKaPpmygCC_o0pVNe0s2TtQSzje2PdHzPF5ErFtmcM>\n' + '534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n' + '534-5.7.14 Learn more at\n' + '534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 m14sm3076179iow.54 - gsmtp', responseCode: 534, command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }
11:58:37.214 AM
contactWithMe
Function execution took 647 ms, finished with status code: 500
11:58:37.216 AM
contactWithMe
[2022-01-07 10:58:37] INFO [iImP28YjIl0] Connection closed
```

What have I missed? Thank you in advance. Have a great day!

Comment: I ran into the same problem, were you able to fix it?

Comment: Hi Kiki! There was some kind of Google security check :/ For each deploy I think I reauthenticate myself with google. I mean IF you want to send an email you will get a notification from google that is about "some has logged in with your for gmail account" - and as I said before you should re-accept for each deploy. I hope I could help. Have a great day.